# SQL Server 2019 Always On performance

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

We are in process of development of project which will process around 51 000 000 records daily (~around 500-600 inserts per second). We choose Always On solution in SQL Server 2019 which will contain:

1. One Primary Server
2. Three replicas which has to work in
   synchronously mode

According to my checks (at this same machine) with use of stored procedure (inserting data to main table) I got results:

- **Always On (1 PRIMARY, 3 REPLICAS):**
  ~260 inserts per second (1 BATCH - 10 000 INSERTS)
  ~440 inserts per second (2 BATCHES - 10 000 INSERT RUN AT THE SAME TIME)
- **Without Always On (1 PRIMARY):**
  ~620 insert per second (1 BATCH - 10 000 INSERTS)
  ~1200 insert per second (2 BATCHES - 10 000 INSERT RUN AT THE SAME TIME)

**My questions are:**

1. Do you have similiar experience with decrease of efficiency according to implementation Always On architecture ? (in my case it is around 2x times faster in solution without Always on)
2. Could you recomend similar solution in SQL Server ?

Comment: There is no free lunch. If you want synchronous replication it will always have a performance impact, no matter the technology used. You should be looking at target performance you need to meet, otherwise relative performance impact is rather pointless.

Comment: Using what code? With what hardware specs? Since you use synchronous mode, the primary has to wait for the replicas to complete. If the replicas are slow, the primary will have to wait. If the code doesn't use bulk operations, each row will generate a transaction log that will have to be replicated *and* applied on the replicas. I can't find any docs that explain how Always ON affect `bcp` or `BULK INSERT`

Comment: I was testing on executing procedure (10 000 times) which contains only one insert to one big table (45 columns) with several datatypes. Servers are in VMs with 4GB of ram and Xeon).

Comment: Why the requirement for synchronous replication? For ~500 inserts/sec, and 51 million/day, that seems like a silly requirement. Though what do I know? Can you give a specific reason?

Comment: Because we can not have even small posibility to loss any data.

Comment: That has nothing to do with synchronicity @axdna.

Comment: You want to process 500-600 inserts _per second_, synchronously write that data to _three replicas_, on servers with _4GB of memory_ (less than my phone), and you're complaining about write performance?

Comment: You might want to post the table DDL--if the table is not designed properly it can greatly reduce insert performance.  You also need to state what kind of network link there is between each node of the cluster.  To hope to pull this off you probably need 10 gbps and enterprise-grade SSDs (at least for the transaction logs).  But inserting one row at a time--should be lots of room for improvement there.